# hibernate mysql dialect 8 unexpected token: ENGINE

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate to get a connection to a mysql database.

Like in various tutorials suggested I setup my application properties like this:

```
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_schema
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Now if i leave out the hibernate dialect, it uses `HSQLDialect` which shows the creation of two tables based on my two entities. But none of them are shown in MySQL Workbench...

If I use the dialect shown above I get the following error:

```
2022-04-12 13:33:50.453  WARN 26016 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table booking_entry (id bigint not null, employee_id bigint not null, project_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table booking_entry (id bigint not null, employee_id bigint not null, project_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ENGINE
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: ENGINE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

So basically `unexpected token: ENGINE` is the error.

The rest of my project is rather basic like in [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) spring tutorial, but I used JPA Repositories instead of CRUD.

Ultimatly I am trying to connect a MS Access DB and a MySQL Database. I got everything up and running for a while but now the MySQL part screwed up so I created this simple example with the same problem.

Any suggestions would really help, since I am allready trying to solve this for a few days...

I allready tried to run the `create table booking_entry (id bigint not null, employee_id bigint not null, project_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB` command on MySQL Workbench which worked fine. So it has nothing to do with my Database.

Comment: Use `spring.datasource.url` instead of `spring.datasource.jdbcurl`. There is no database connection being made and it will use H2/HSQLDB as default (which is propably on your classpath, I suggest to remove it). You are basically firing a MySQL query to an H2/HSQLDB database which won't understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_schema 
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: Adding the driver-class-name actually did the trick... Not sure why, because 2 months ago it worked without the driver-class-name but I take it :D Thanks a lot @Rajvee !!!!